# Metric tensor relations

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, gravity, metric-tensor

I need to check some simple tensor relations for continuing my calculations. Please write me if you think anyone is incorrect.

P.S.: I know this is very simple question, but i need to be assured about them before keep going in my analysis.

$Q_{\alpha}=g^{\mu\nu}Q_{\alpha\mu\nu},\hspace{0.5cm}\hat{Q}_{\alpha}=g^{\mu\nu}Q_{\mu\alpha\nu},\hspace{0.5cm}Q^{\alpha}=g_{\mu\nu}Q^{\alpha\mu\nu}
,\hspace{0.5cm}\hat{Q}^{\alpha}=g_{\mu\nu}Q^{\mu\alpha\nu},\hspace{0.5cm}Q_{\nu}=g^{\alpha\mu}Q_{\nu\alpha\mu},\nonumber\\
Q_{\mu}=g^{\alpha\nu}Q_{\mu\alpha\nu},\hspace{0.5cm},g_{\mu\nu}g^{\mu\nu}=n\hspace{0.5cm},g_{\mu\nu}g^{\mu\alpha}=g_{\mu\nu}g^{\alpha\mu}=g_{\nu\mu}g^{\mu\alpha}=\delta_{\nu}^{\alpha},\hspace{0.5cm}Q^{\alpha\mu\nu}=-g^{\alpha\beta}\nabla_{\beta}g^{\mu\nu}.$

Here, $Q_{\alpha\mu\nu}$ is the non-metricity tensor. $Q_{\alpha}$ and $\hat{Q}_{\alpha}$ are independent traces of the non-metricity tensor.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The first definition on the first line is identical to the definition on the second line, $Q_{\alpha} = g^{\mu \nu} Q_{\alpha \mu \nu}$. (I'm not sure what the $ْ\ $  is doing there, perhaps this is an error.) Everything else looks fine, they're all just definitions anyway.

Comment: Thanks Eletie. Yes it was an error in typing. I removed it.

Comment: @Mehdi Cool, all looks good then! You can remove one of them as they're just duplicates now.